# Apache James TestContainers connection refused

Tags: docker, testing, testcontainers, james, apache-james

I am running the equivalent of

```
docker run --name james_run -p "25:25" -p "465:465" -p "587:587" -p "143:143"  -p "993:993" --volume "$PWD/conf:/root/conf/" --volume "$PWD/var:/root/var/" apache/james:latest
```

in TestContainers

```
            james = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("apache/james")).withExposedPorts(25, 465, 587, 143, 993, 8000).withFileSystemBind(EmailServerIT.class.getClassLoader().getResource("conf").getPath(),"/root/conf", BindMode.READ_WRITE).withFileSystemBind(EmailServerIT.class.getClassLoader().getResource("var").getPath(),"/root/var", BindMode.READ_WRITE);
```

But am getting a connection refused error whenever I try to send to the SMTP port:

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection error (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused))
```

I have set  to try and avoid needing a keystore but am having no luck.

Please advise

Comment: Can you share the client code are you using to connect against the Apache James, please? Take into account you need to use the random port provided by Testcontainers james.getMappedPort(<port>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example Project Tree

```
DemoTestContainerLab
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── example
        │       └── SimpleJamesTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── logback-test.xml
            └── testcontainers.properties
```

### Sample Code

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoTestContainerLab</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.10.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.19.0</testcontainers.version>
        <jakarta.mail.version>2.1.2</jakarta.mail.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.mail.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

#### SimpleJamesTest.java

```
package example;

import jakarta.mail.*;
import jakarta.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait;

import java.util.Properties;


public class SimpleJamesTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        GenericContainer<?> james = new GenericContainer<>("apache/james:demo-3.8.0")
                .withExposedPorts(143,25,4000,465,587,80,8000,993)
                .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*AddUser command executed sucessfully.*", 3));;
        james.start();
        Integer smtpPort =  james.getMappedPort(25);
        String to = "user01@james.local";
        String from = "user01@james.local";
        final String username = "user01@james.local";
        final String password = "1234";
        String host = "localhost";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort );
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject("This is a Demo Jakarta Mail!");
            message.setText("Just test Jakarta Mail use smtp protocol sned mail");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Email Message Sent Successfully");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### testcontainers.properties

```
docker.client.strategy=org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy
TESTCONTAINERS_DOCKER_SOCKET_OVERRIDE=/var/run/docker.sock
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

### Notes

#### Docker image

I use docker image is this: `apache/james:demo-3.8.0`
It will auto create mail domain, mail user.

Mail Domain:

- `james.local`

Mail user:

- `user01@james.local`
- `user02@james.local`
- `user03@james.local`

#### Config Exposed Ports

Run command: `docker inspect apache/james:demo-3.8.0` , find exposed ports.

```
"ExposedPorts": {
                "143/tcp": {},
                "25/tcp": {},
                "4000/tcp": {},
                "465/tcp": {},
                "587/tcp": {},
                "80/tcp": {},
                "8000/tcp": {},
                "993/tcp": {}
            },
```

then use it in code:

`.withExposedPorts(143,25,4000,465,587,80,8000,993)`

#### Wait James Container Start OK

If we use command run docker

`sudo docker run -it apache/james:demo-3.8.0`

we will see the last message is :

```
11:27:29.319 [INFO ] o.a.j.GuiceJamesServer - JAMES server started
wait-for-it.sh: localhost:9999 is available after 8 seconds
AddDomain command executed sucessfully in 271 ms.
AddUser command executed sucessfully in 311 ms.
AddUser command executed sucessfully in 261 ms.
AddUser command executed sucessfully in 219 ms.
```

We must wait container add user 3 times.

then use it in our code:

`.waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*AddUser command executed sucessfully.*", 3));;`

And TestContainers will mapped original smtp port 25 to some other port in host.

We need use code to get it:

`Integer smtpPort =  james.getMappedPort(25);`

Then we can use it in our smtp send mail code.

`props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort );`

### Run Test

Run Test Command

```
mvn test
```

Run Result - SMTP Debug Message

```
... skip some messages ...
MAIL FROM:<user01@james.local>
250 2.1.0 Sender <user01@james.local> OK
RCPT TO:<user01@james.local>
250 2.1.5 Recipient <user01@james.local> OK
DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   user01@james.local
DATA
354 Ok Send data ending with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
Date: Wed, 27 Sep 2023 19:49:14 +0800 (CST)
From: user01@james.local
To: user01@james.local
Message-ID: <471004142.0.1695815354250@demo-pc-ae23f827>
Subject: This is a Demo Jakarta Mail!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Just test Jakarta Mail use smtp protocol sned mail
.
250 2.6.0 Message received
DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
QUIT
221 2.0.0 473f3c567c98 Service closing transmission channel
Email Message Sent Successfully
```